# Finding the coordinates of a point on a sine graph and it's x,y phase shifts given axis intercepts

Tags: trigonometry

[This is the question from my textbook:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/19RoF.png)[image]

The correct answer for the coordinates of $A$ is $\left(\frac{2\pi}{3},\frac{3}{2}\right)$. I've tried making three equations and solving by substitution for $k$ and $c$, but I do not get the correct values. Here's the equations I made:

$0=sin(\frac{4\pi}{3})+c$

$0=sin(\frac{2\pi}{3})+c$

$0=sin(2\pi)+c$

Correct value for $k$ is $\frac{\pi}{6}$, for $c$ it is $\frac{1}{2}$.

Help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: You should include the work you've done so far in the body of the question. What are the three equations you made? What are the substitution steps? Also, for future math formatting, check out this link as a guide for using Mathjax: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: um there is no 0 at 2π/3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

b) is easier than a) so I am going to start there.

the function is period with period $2\pi$

that is $f(x) = f(x+2n\pi)$

if $f(x) = 0$ then $f(2\pi) = 0,f(-2\pi) = 0$ etc.

In the interval $[-4\pi,0]$

$0-4\pi, \frac {4\pi}{3}-4\pi, -2\pi, \frac {4\pi}{3} - 2\pi, 0$

or,
$-4\pi, -\frac {8\pi}{3}, -2\pi, -\frac {2\pi}{3}, 0$

c)
Every period there are two solutions.  There are two in the cycle $[0,2\pi)$ and two more in $[2\pi,4\pi)$, etc.

there are 8 solutions in $[0,8\pi)$

there is no solution in $[8\pi, 9\pi)$

a)
Phase-shift:

The maximal and minimal values of $\sin(x-k)-c$ will be half-way between the zeros.

$x = \frac {2\pi}{3}, \frac {5\pi}{3}$

The maximal and minimal values of an un-shifted sin function are at $x= \frac {\pi}{2},x= \frac {3\pi}{2}$

the phase-shift is $\frac {\pi}{2} - \frac {2\pi}{3} = -\frac {\pi}{6}$

Vertical shift:

$\sin(0-\frac {\pi}{6}) + c = 0\\
-\frac 12 + c = 0$

$f(x) = \sin(x-\frac {\pi}{6}) + \frac 12$

and finally A

$f(\frac {2\pi}{3}) = \sin(\frac {\pi}{2}) + \frac 12 = \frac 32$

Comment: Finally get it; thank you so much :)

Answer (score 1):

**hint**

from the graph, we derive that

$$f (0)=f (4\frac \pi 3)=0$$

thus

$$\sin (-k)+c=\sin (4\frac \pi 3-k)+c=0$$

from here,
$$-k=\pi-(4\frac \pi 3-k) $$

You can finish.

Answer (score 0):

$\sin(2π-k)+c=0$

This is equivalent to $\sin(k)=c$

$\sin(\frac{4π}{3}-k)+c=0$

$-\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\cos(k)+\frac{1}{2}\sin(k)+\sin(k)=0$

$-\sqrt{3}\cos(k)=-3\sin(k)$

$\tan(k)=\frac{\sqrt{3}}{3}$

$k=\frac{π}{6}$

$c=\sin(\frac{π}{6})=\frac{1}{2}$